# How to add hyperlinks in Description in SharePoint list columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I need your help to add hyperlink and change the color of the description when you create a new a column. Please see the attachment. for instance in here I want to add http://google.com as hyperlink so users can click on it. Also I need to change the text color to red. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the description field when you edit the list column, per my knowledge we do not have an option to customize it or adding rich text. You can only add single text content.

Answer (score 0):

As Jerry mentioned, the Description property for the SharePoint list columns is just a plain text and nothing more. You can't add any hyperlinks or text formatting.

Comment: I managed to do it by using below code:  var an = $("td > span.ms-metadata > a")
  an[0].text = "Western  Legislation - Home"